# Reading a file object in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, file, file-io, arraylist

How do you read a file object in java?

```
File file= new File(filePathName);
         if (file.exists()){
         filesArrayList.add(file);
         }
```

Depending on the number of processors threads are sent:
a file and a starting (lower bound) and end (upper bound) to read.

```
File inputFile= (File)filesArrList.get(i);
BufferedInputStream bis= new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream (inputFile));
while ((line=bis.readLine())!=null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

Is it possible to read the files in the arraylist?

Comment: Yes. It is possible. That is exactly what you are doing. What is the question?

Comment: You don't know how to read a file?

Comment: No the code above looks as if it would work but it does not read the contents of the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1 :** You can read files stored in ArrayList through the following way.

**2 :** Yes it is also possible to read files stored in array list.

```
public class ReadingFiles {

    BufferedReader br;
    ArrayList<File> list = new ArrayList<>();

    ReadingFiles() {
        list.add(new File((getClass().getResource("file1.txt")).getPath()));
        readFile(list.get(0));
        list.add(new File((getClass().getResource("file2.txt")).getPath()));
        readFile(list.get(1));
    }

    public void readFile(File file) {
        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            String line = br.readLine();
            while (line != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
                line = br.readLine();
            }
            br.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Sorry");
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        new ReadingFiles();
    }
}
```